# How is this question about divination too broad?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

[Target of divination when magically altered?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/90630/target-of-divination-when-magically-altered)

This question was recently closed as "Too Broad." While a specific question about the way a specific spell works would have allowed me to write a more specific answer, and I left a comment to that effect, I believe that the question was answerable in its current form (and I answered it). If the question was too broad to be answerable, that would necessarily imply that my answer was too broad to be useful - and I don't think that is the case.

Why was this question put on hold?

Comment: It's possible to have great answers to poor questions, but great answers rarely save poor questions from being closed--for example, a lucky guess may let someone answer a question which is very unclearly worded, but that doesn't make the question itself any more clear. You may find [this Stack blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) interesting/useful.

Answer (score 5):

## It's two questions

Here's the first one:

> What happens when you have a distinct item that is easily searched for with divination spells, and that item gets magically changed. How does it being changed affect it as a target of the divination spells?
>
> Examples of this could be a very distinct statue which has been stone shaped into another form.

That's all about objects. That's totally answerable.

Here's the second one:

> Or someone under a polymorph or even transmutation effect. At what point would the divination spell stop considering it [the creature] as being the same target?

That's huge and deserves its own question. That will likely require an answer that demonstrates experience with high-level divination effects as well as form-changing magic and the ins and outs of the various methods of bringing back the dead.

Chop off that second example, and the question should be good.

Comment: @TimC I didn't even notice the question's second part when I wrote my comment (that I later deleted) on that question! *Mea culpa.*

Answer (score 0):

Without an extensive knowledge of the game, the fact that there are not that many spells that could have the desired effect might not be evident.

Your current answer anyway builds on the fact that the question talks about finding an object, but you should also consider that it asks about divinations in general. How would a polymorphed animal react to Detect Animals? (...and so on)